# jQuery : difficulty loading multiple external html files

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to load a number of small .html files using jQuery, and have them all put into the DOM before I execute a certain part of code. But this is proving extremely difficult. I can make it do ONE file well enough, but anything I try to make it handle multiples just doesn't function and I cannot comprehend why.

This is the code that can do ONE file.

```
var templates = (function ($, host) {
    // begin to load external templates from a given path and inject them into the DOM
    return {
        // use jQuery $.get to load the templates asynchronously
        load: function (url, target, event) {
            var loader = $.get(url)
                .success(function (data) {
                    // on success, add the template to the targeted DOM element
                    $(target).append(data);
                })
                .error(function (data) {

                })
                .complete(function () {
                    $(host).trigger(event, [url]);
                });
        }
    };
})(jQuery, document);
```

This is used as follows;

```
templates.load("file1.html",
    "#templates-container", "file1-loaded");


$(document).on("file1-loaded", function (e) {
    // execute the rest of the page
});
```

This falls flat if I need to load more than one file though. So I tried this ...

```
(function ($, host) {
    $.fn.templates = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            queue: [],
            element: this,
            onLoaded: function () { }
        }, options);

        this.add = function (url) {
            settings.queue.push(url);
            return settings.element;
        }

        this.load = function () {
            $.each(settings.queue, function (index, value) {
                $.get(value).success(function (data) {
                    $(settings.element).append(data);
                });
            });

            settings.onLoaded.call();
        }

        return settings.element;
    }
})(jQuery, document);
```

Which is intended to work like this ...

```
$('#templates-container').templates({
    onLoaded: function () {
        // execute the rest of the code
    }
}).add('file1.html').add('file2.html').done();
```

But it just outright fails, and it gives me no indication as to why. I don't even get an error message. But the onLoaded never gets called properly.

Comment: first version works fine for me...here's a [working plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/anmNzGLIZMCyzAyUt3fr)

Comment: That isn't the way I am needing to use it. You're doing two separate loads. I need to do both loads in ONE call, so that the event only raises when they are ALL complete.

Comment: And it needs to take an infinite number of files, not just one.

Comment: OK that wasn't clear...you just stated that it all failed. Description could use some upgrading. Can build a deferred array and resolve it when all are done. Give me a few

Comment: Oh, I am very sorry. I thought I had said that. I will get to updating the text. My apologies.

Comment: take a look again ( same link)... I set it so only call your method once and pass it an array of files. Final event only triggers after they all are loaded

Comment: Oh! Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to do. It was the deferred part I was missing! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that sends an array to loader function , pushes the promise for each request into an array, then when the whole promise array is resolved using `$.when` your event fires

```
var templates = (function ($, host) {
    // begin to load external templates from a given path and inject them into the DOM
    return {
        // use jQuery $.get to load the templates asynchronously
        load: function (templateArray, target, event) {
            var defferArray = [];
            $.each(templateArray, function (idx, url) {
                var loader = $.get(url)
                    .success(function (data) {
                    // on success, add the template to the targeted DOM element
                    $(target).append(data);
                })
                defferArray.push(loader);
            })

            $.when.apply(null, defferArray).done(function () {
                $(host).trigger(event);
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery, document);

$(document).on("files-loaded", function () {
    $("#content").append("<p>All done!</p>");
})


$(function () {
    var templateArray = ["file1.html", "file2.html"]
    templates.load(templateArray, "#content", "files-loaded");
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/anmNzGLIZMCyzAyUt3fr?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: this is same as other link in comments...just added as answer for others